Not using all the arguements from pytest mark parametrize
I have two functions I want to test with two similar inputs and different outputs.
I was trying to encapsulate them within a class and only have the parameterize decorator on the class
I came up with code similar to this
import pytest

def foo(A, B):
    return A + B

def bar(A, B):
    return A - B

@pytest.mark.parametrize("A,B,foo_output,bar_output", [
(1,2,3,-1),
(6,3,9,3),
...
])
class TestClass:

   def test_foo(self, A, B, foo_output):
       assert foo(A, B) == foo_output

   def test_bar(self, A, B, bar_output):
       assert bar(A, B) == bar_output

Pytest isn't letting me run these tests because the function test_foo isn't taking the bar_output argument and vice versa.
ERROR test/test_foo_bar.py::TestClass - Failed: In test_foo: function uses no argument 'bar_output'

ERROR test/test_foo_bar.py::TestClass - Failed: In test_bar: function uses no argument 'foo_output'

Just adding unused arguements foo_output and bar_output in the functions work but does not seem like the best solution and I could not find any standard solution for this.
I fixed this by creating a fixture within the class to take these arguments as a sink but again, unsure if that's the best approach to the problem
class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _ignore_args(self, foo_output, bar_output):
        pass

    ...

What will be the best solution to accomplish this?

You can parameterize the individual tests with the expected arguments:
import pytest

def foo(A, B):
    return A + B

def bar(A, B):
    return A - B

test_parameters = [
  (1,2,3,-1),
  (6,3,9,3),
]

class TestClass:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "A,B,foo_output",
        [(a,b,foo) for a, b, foo, _ in test_parameters],
    )
    def test_foo(self, A, B, foo_output):
        assert foo(A, B) == foo_output

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "A,B,bar_output",
        [(a,b,bar) for a, b, _, bar in test_parameters],
    )
    def test_bar(self, A, B, bar_output):
        assert bar(A, B) == bar_output

